# Create a custom role with no (or minimal) permissions

Tags: google-cloud-iam

I am working on an application that has several custom roles that do not map to the existing IAM roles or permissions. e.g. Sales Department, Administrator, or Approver.

I would like to create these custom roles in IAM and assign users to them. However, in order to create a custom role, I need to select at least one permission from the list of predefined permissions.

Is there a way to create a custom role with no permissions or with a minimal permission that has no side effects?

Answer (score 0):

You may create roles with no permissions:

```
Request

POST https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[[PROJECT-ID]]/roles
{
 "role": {
 },
 "roleId": "test"
}

Response

200

- Show headers -

{
 "name": "projects/[[PROJECT-ID]]/roles/test",
 "etag": "BwWEuBNyx4k="
}
```

Comment: I wonder if that can be done from google cloud ui: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles