# What does the "internal" user type oauth setting do when there is no organisation assigned to the project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth

I am integrating a simple YouTube plugin into a CMS and have set up my OAuth credentials and settings in the relevant GCP API & Services section.

The **User Type** setting can be set to either [**Internal** or **External**](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpublic-and-internal-applications). The Internal setting says "*In this mode, your app is limited to Google Workspace users within your organisation.*"

The project I am working on has no organisation assigned. What does this setting do in this instance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Project with consent set to internal / Who is a "member of my organization" and how do I manage members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381793/google-project-with-consent-set-to-internal-who-is-a-member-of-my-organizatio)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after further investigation - in short: **Organisations which you are not a member of are not shown**.

In my situation, the organisation is that which the owner of the project (the person who set it up), belongs to. Presumably, because I am an admin but not a member of the organisation, I do not have the permissions to see this.

Rather than tell me this, the UI goes to the extent of actually telling me *incorrect information* - that the project has no organisation. This a valid, but entirely different state!

Extremely confusing and I would argue - a bug. Many aspects of the UI and processes refer to an organisation, which always says "No organisation" for myself, despite the fact that on the same screens for the owner, it clearly states the assigned organisation.
The only way I could figure this out was to share screenshots of the same screens between the owner and I.

In regards to the oauth user type, I have to assume that it applies to the owner's organisation.